# ACPI problem with MSI laptop

Tags: acpi

I have a MSI laptop, but i can't use any distribution whitout disabling acpi.

I would like to know if there are a distribution compatible with MSI ACPI.

Distribution not working with acpi :

- fedora 24
- fedora 25
- Manjaro 16
- Ubuntu 16
- Opensuse tumbleweed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A distribution which work without acpi=off is LinuxMint.
You have to put for the installation of LInuxmint acpi=off but after, when i loot at in grub configuration, i can see there is not acpi=off or other acpi argument and all working well.
My laptop is a MSI GPF 6QE.